# how to write Rails3 routes exceptions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Hello
I have an application where URI looks like http://mysite.com/post1 or http://mysite.com/post2 etc.
But with routing as this i can't get images because it stored at http://mysite.com/images/ folder in my server.
So how to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Compass](http://compass-style.org/). It is a stylesheet authoring framework which allows you to use helpers such as [image_url](http://compass-style.org/docs/reference/compass/helpers/urls/) in scss stylesheets. `image_url` can be used in combination with a configuration variable `asset_host`, that prepends that path to images in your stylesheets.

Here is an example:

```
.content{
  background: image_url("background.png") "no-repeat";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using the path_to_image() or image_tag() helper?